# how to have multi auth for 2 different tables

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am building a medical system which has 2 tables, one for patines and the other for doctors which can not be together in only one table. and I need to have multi authentication. what I have reached so far is that I have a login and dashboard with Laravel's laravel/ui package for the doctors which are protected by auth middleware.

my question here is how can I make another login and dashboard for the patient. I have searched for the solution but all I found is about put them together which can not be in my case

Comment: its all the same, it just depends what 'guard' you are using ... its the same exact functionality you are just telling one to use one guard and the other to use a different guard

Comment: Just edit `config/auth.php` and create new guard. The question needs more focus, nobody is going to write an authentication system for you.